# three.js import svg path from image

Tags: image, svg, three.js

I am trying to import svg paths in three.js taken from svg images

I found [this example](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=extr#webgl_geometry_extrude_shapes2) that uses the following format:

```
obj.paths = [
    /// Taipei City
    "M366.2182,108.9780 L368.0329,110.3682 L367.5922,112.4411 L369.9258,116.0311 L368.9827,117.3543 " +
    "L371.5686,119.8491 L370.5599,121.7206 L372.9314,124.8009 L368.8889,126.7603 L369.2695,130.7622 " +
    "L366.1499,130.3388 L363.4698,128.1161 L362.9256,125.6018 L360.8153,126.4025 L360.2968,124.3588 " +
    "L361.9519,121.1623 L360.4475,118.7162 L358.1163,117.8678 L358.7094,115.7577 L361.6243,112.4576 Z",
    /// Keelung City
    "M380.2689,113.3850 L383.5604,114.2370 L383.7404,114.2386 L385.4082,115.6247 L384.9725,117.4631 " +
    "L381.6681,117.9439 L383.0209,121.0914 L379.4649,122.7061 L373.4987,118.8487 L372.0980,114.7589 " +
    "L377.9716,112.0707 Z",
    /// Taipei County
    "M359.4486,155.6690 L357.0422,152.7420 L355.1688,148.0173 L357.1186,145.8045 L354.1323,141.2242 " +
    "L351.1807,141.6609 L348.9387,140.5372 L349.5415,137.8396 L347.5174,136.1694 L347.6299,129.2327 " +
    "L351.4192,128.8067 L354.2518,125.3113 L352.5805,121.8038 L349.3190,120.9429 L344.3277,116.7676 " +
    "L350.9772,115.1221 L354.5759,112.5371 L354.5667,110.6949 L357.4098,105.7489 L362.3963,101.8443 " +
    "L364.4415,101.0819 L364.5314,101.0828 L364.6209,101.1230 L364.7698,101.2029 L368.1221,101.5115 " +
    "L371.7216,104.1338 L372.2958,106.7261 L375.5949,109.6971 L377.0415,108.8875 L377.0737,108.6526 " +
    "L377.4037,108.6165 L376.8840,109.7091 L376.7323,109.9037 L377.9416,112.0705 L371.7970,114.8736 " + 
    "L374.0935,119.4031 L380.7848,122.7963 L382.6529,121.9897 L381.5792,117.8256 L385.0339,117.3069 " +
    "L385.4082,115.6247 L388.7014,116.3969 L389.8697,116.6024 L390.0206,116.4860 L391.0396,116.6118 " +
    "L394.6665,116.9929 L394.4694,119.2255 L394.3172,119.4987 L395.3792,121.8977 L395.2728,124.0526 " +
    "L397.2123,125.6350 L401.1709,126.2516 L401.2612,126.2130 L401.4086,126.6060 L400.1992,127.7733 " +
    "L399.7769,128.0446 L399.6247,128.3179 L398.1779,129.0521 L394.2418,129.2969 L388.7324,130.9385 " +
    "L389.2782,134.0003 L383.7237,137.0111 L381.7445,139.9336 L379.7001,139.9546 L376.1539,143.0580 " +
    "L371.3022,144.1094 L368.6009,146.5914 L368.7361,151.1399 L363.6153,154.4980 " +
    /// Taipei County hole.
    "M363.4600,128.3904 L366.6300,130.3829 L369.3732,129.3913 L369.5603,125.6695 L374.3989,125.1677 " +
    "L370.8412,123.6440 L371.0684,118.8252 L369.0431,117.3157 L369.6882,115.7936 L367.8578,112.8749 " +
    "L368.1217,110.4867 L366.5152,109.2554 L361.9554,112.3435 L358.1163,117.8678 L361.7218,120.2192 " +
    "L360.7261,126.3232 L362.8064,125.5221 Z"];
```

I found [this example](http://codepen.io/A__L/pen/RPKdmN) that uses the following format:

```
obj.paths = [
    /// Taipei City
        "M20.4,0.4C12.6,44.5,4.7,88.7,2.6,133.5S4.1,223.7,18.9,266c5.9,1.6,11.6-2.8,16.1-6.9c12.2-11,24.7-22.3,32.3-36.8c5.9-11.4,8.6-24.2,10-36.9c3-26.8,0.8-53.9-1.7-80.8c-1.5-16.6-3.2-33.2-4.9-49.8c-0.9-8.5-1.9-17.4-6.1-24.9c-8.2-14.6-26.3-20.4-43-22.3c-0.4,6.2-0.8,12.4-1.3,18.6",
    /// Keelung City
    "M34.6,172.4c7.6-0.4,15.1-1.4,22.5-3.1c9.7-2.2,20.4-6.6,23.8-16c2.9-7.9-0.6-16.9-6.4-23.1c-5.8-6.1-13.4-10-20.8-14c-4.2-2.3-8.5-4.7-13.2-4.7c-7.8-0.1-14.2,6.1-21.7,8.4c-2.5,0.8-5.2,1.2-7.3,2.7c-1.7,1.2-2.8,3-3.8,4.8c-3.4,6.1-5.8,12.8-6,19.8c-0.1,7,2.3,14.2,7.5,18.8C15.9,172.1,25.7,172.9,34.6,172.4z"];
```

I tried to import the svg path from [this svg image](https://css-tricks.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/kiwi.svg) (`<path d="..."`) having the following format:

```
obj.paths = [
    "M210.333,65.331C104.367,66.105-12.349,150.637,1.056,276.449c4.303,40.393,18.533,63.704,52.171,79.03  c36.307,16.544,57.022,54.556,50.406,112.954c-9.935,4.88-17.405,11.031-19.132,20.015c7.531-0.17,14.943-0.312,22.59,4.341  c20.333,12.375,31.296,27.363,42.979,51.72c1.714,3.572,8.192,2.849,8.312-3.078c0.17-8.467-1.856-17.454-5.226-26.933  c-2.955-8.313,3.059-7.985,6.917-6.106c6.399,3.115,16.334,9.43,30.39,13.098c5.392,1.407,5.995-3.877,5.224-6.991  c-1.864-7.522-11.009-10.862-24.519-19.229c-4.82-2.984-0.927-9.736,5.168-8.351l20.234,2.415c3.359,0.763,4.555-6.114,0.882-7.875  c-14.198-6.804-28.897-10.098-53.864-7.799c-11.617-29.265-29.811-61.617-15.674-81.681c12.639-17.938,31.216-20.74,39.147,43.489  c-5.002,3.107-11.215,5.031-11.332,13.024c7.201-2.845,11.207-1.399,14.791,0c17.912,6.998,35.462,21.826,52.982,37.309  c3.739,3.303,8.413-1.718,6.991-6.034c-2.138-6.494-8.053-10.659-14.791-20.016c-3.239-4.495,5.03-7.045,10.886-6.876  c13.849,0.396,22.886,8.268,35.177,11.218c4.483,1.076,9.741-1.964,6.917-6.917c-3.472-6.085-13.015-9.124-19.18-13.413  c-4.357-3.029-3.025-7.132,2.697-6.602c3.905,0.361,8.478,2.271,13.908,1.767c9.946-0.925,7.717-7.169-0.883-9.566  c-19.036-5.304-39.891-6.311-61.665-5.225c-43.837-8.358-31.554-84.887,0-90.363c29.571-5.132,62.966-13.339,99.928-32.156  c32.668-5.429,64.835-12.446,92.939-33.85c48.106-14.469,111.903,16.113,204.241,149.695c3.926,5.681,15.819,9.94,9.524-6.351  c-15.893-41.125-68.176-93.328-92.13-132.085c-24.581-39.774-14.34-61.243-39.957-91.247  c-21.326-24.978-47.502-25.803-77.339-17.365c-23.461,6.634-39.234-7.117-52.98-31.273C318.42,87.525,265.838,64.927,210.333,65.331  z M445.731,203.01c6.12,0,11.112,4.919,11.112,11.038c0,6.119-4.994,11.111-11.112,11.111s-11.038-4.994-11.038-11.111  C434.693,207.929,439.613,203.01,445.731,203.01z"];
```

But I have an error:

> Uncaught Error: weird path command

I am trying to import it in this way because I would like to import existing svg images

Comment: if I get it correctly, there must not be spaces before commands, thus, try to remove the space between `z` and `M445.731`

Comment: Removing the last space did the trick!

Comment: Is it possible to see what and how you do? Any jsfiddle? For example, in the string of your importing svg that you provided here, there are multiple spaces there.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/neodev2/8c3f3e3b5e74125c79410842fc66868e

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a weird path. You have two svg paths in your string. It looks like in your original codepen link that the library wants an array of single svg paths.

Towards the end:

```
.. 333,65.331  z M445.731,2 ..
```

z terminates an svg path. So this syntax is incorrect as this is two paths in one. I'm certain if you fix this up so you are sending in an array of 2 svg paths, like

```
.. 333,65.331z", "M445.731,2 ..
```

it will work. [Demo](http://codepen.io/bitten/pen/vyMqZo)

Comment: In the second example does not work. I splitted in two strings after the z but I have the same error

Comment: where is the 2nd example?